# How do I get an iframe to work in Flask?

Tags: python, iframe, flask

Here's how my Flask app is laid out.

```
Project/
  main.py
  Template/
    web-form.html
    index.html
```

I want `web-form.html` to have an iframe that pulls content from `index.html`.

`main.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app=    Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', template_folder='template')

@app.route('/')
def graphic():
    return render_template('web-form.html')
```

`web-form.html`:

```
<iframe src="index.html"></iframe>
```

But I instead see a 404 error where the iframe should be. How do I fix this?

Comment: You aren't serving anything at `/index.html`.

Comment: @Vallentin Updated with a new route for `/index`, still getting 404

Comment: You need a route for `/index.html` not `/index`